# Cassandra GUI for windows clients

Tags: cassandra, client

Could somebody please suggest me a good GUI client tool for Cassandra on Windows? I need something like Robo 3T (formerly Robomongo) for MongoDB.

Comment: Have you found what were you looking for? :)

Comment: https://javaresolutions.blogspot.com/2018/04/opensource-db-ui-tool-for-cassandra-db.html .  I followed this on MAC, and I connected successfully to Cassandra running on docker

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DataStax (the maintainer of Apache Cassandra) has a tool called [DevCenter](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-devcenter/devcenter/dcInstallation.html) . I use it, it gets the job done. A bit newer tool is [DataStax Studio](https://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-studio/studio/introduction.html), which is more of a graph visualization tool, but I haven't used it, also check the pricing.
[OpsCenter](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-opscenter) is a monitoring tool. It works with Apace Cassandra (the free one), with disabled features (all features availale in DataStax Enterprise).

Comment: Try the https://tableplus.com/ as well